# mysql do while routine erring

Tags: mysql, while-loop

MySQL v5.6.17. I am getting an incorrect syntax error on the first line when stepping through this (generic error 1064 - 'Script line: 33   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare x int' at line 1
"). I have looked at examples of other do-whiles but step through execution of this code hasn't even made it that far. Very puzzled. I would also appreciate any suggestions on whether this do-while method is most efficient. Essentially I need to loop through split_col_table thousands of rows looking at DelimitedCol column which hold delimited values, and remove each delimited value into a separate ROW into report, then I am deleting that previous value and the delimiter from split_col_table until there are no delimiters left. At the end I will make a final pass to get the remainder of the values out of DelimitedCol in split_col_table.

Code relevant to the loop:

```
    declare x int;
    set x = select count(*) from split_col_table where DelimitedCol like '%;%';

    while x > 0 DO

      INSERT INTO report (SELECT id, val1,LEFT(DelimitedCol,LOCATE(';',DelimitedCol)-1)         FROM split_col_table where DelimitedCol like '%;%');

      UPDATE split_col_table SET DelimitedCol = RIGHT(DelimitedCol, LENGTH(DelimitedCol)- LOCATE(';',DelimitedCol)) where DelimitedCol > '';

      #repeat until no more ';' in split_col_table
      set x = select count(*) from split_col_table where DelimitedCol like '%;%';

    end while;
```

Comment: How are you sending those commands to the database? Are there maybe any non-printable characters before or around this `declare` statement?

Comment: I am using MySQL Query Browser, a script window, and stepping through. I have other comments that execution skips over fine and just before the declare is #see if there are ; delimited. I cut and pasted the declare into notepad++, made sure there is no other characters, then pasted it back into script. Still erring same.